# Filling column of selected attributes with same number using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

In QGIS, I have selected multiple point features by using "Select by Location" in Vector - Research tool. In the attribute table, I want to fill in a particular number (1) for those selected features.

How do I do it?

I tried with

> replace('grid_id','NULL','1')

[image]

Comment: Do you want to fill an attribute of the selected features with the same value?

Comment: Yes. For example, out of 100 points, I have selected 50 points, in which I want to fill same value. In the attached figure, 'grid_id' is the field I would like to fill a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the `grid_id` field from the drop down menu located at the left side of the `=` sign and write `'1'` If the field type is text, or `1` if the field type is integer. Then press `update selected`.